# Getting the exact clicked button in ListView with Multiple clickable buttons

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I have created a listview with custom ArrayAdapter.This listview consists of textview and two buttons.
To be able to apply the needed action, i need to know how to get which button of these two buttons is clicked.
I can click on any rows and I can receive the onItemClickListener method to run. but i can't find how to make the code get which button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this link in this link you will find how to find onclick of button

http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-listview-example-with-custom-adapter/

http://android-helper.blogspot.in/search/label/ListView